Proving that 1/2 is the least upper bound for $A = \{\frac{(-1)^n}{n}: n \in \mathbf{N} \backslash 0\}$
I'm trying to solve Problem 3(a) from https://pi.math.cornell.edu/~zbnorwood/3110-s19/3110-hw2.pdf (Spring 2019 class). We want to find the supremum of $A$ and to prove it as well.
(a) $A = \{\frac{(-1)^n}{n}: n \in \mathbf{N} \backslash 0\}$
I think $\sup A = 1/2$. To prove this, I need to prove that 1/2 is an upper bound and then I need to prove that it is the least upper bound.
For the first part, I was thinking to do it by contradiction:
Suppose 1/2 is not an upper bound then,
$$
1/2 < \frac{(-1)^n}{n} \\
n/2 < (-1)^n.
$$
If we let $n = 1$, then we'll get 1/2 < -1 which is a contradiction so $1/2$ is an upper bound.
For the second part, I know that there are two strategies.

One is to assume that some other bound $m$ is the least upper bound and then show that $1/2 \leq m$.
The other strategy is use the epsilon lemma which states that $x = \sup A$ iff for all $\epsilon > 0$, there exist an element $a \in A$ such that $a > \sup A - \epsilon$. So I need to find an $n$ such that if we pick any $\epsilon > 0$, then we'll see that $$\frac{(-1)^n}{n} > 1/2 - \epsilon$$

I was thinking for strategy 2, we pick $n = 2$ and so
$$\frac{(-1)^2}{2} > 1/2 - \epsilon \\
  \frac{1}{2} > 1/2 - \epsilon $$
This is true for any $\epsilon > 0$. So 1/2 is the least upper bound.
Is my approach correct? I do feel a little uncomfortable it with and I'm unsure why. I'm also studying this on the side so it's not a formal class where I can seek some validation.
Thank you

When you suppose that $\tfrac{1}{2}$ is not an upper bound that means that $\tfrac{1}{2}< \tfrac{(-1)^n}{n}$ for some $n$. After that you don't get to pick the value of $n$. You can't just say "Let $n=1$".

An upper bound that belongs to the set (a maximum) is always the least upper bound. No need to use $\epsilon$ here.

oh I see @jjagmath! thanks for pointing this mistake! @Mark but how do I prove 1/2 is the maximum?

@nemo Because it is an upper bound and belongs to the set.

right! but how do I know it's an upper bound?

@nemo Didn't you show this in the question?...

@Mark The OP proof is incorrect, so no.

@jjagmath Yeah, but you already pointed on his mistake. So now asking "how do I know" is kind of weird.

I know that the maximum of a set is the supremum of the set as well (did this proof earlier). I'm just struggling with formally writing that 1/2 is an upper bound. Not sure why you find it weird.

@nemo IMO the simplest way is just to note that $-1$ is obviously less than $\frac{1}{2}$, and for each $n\geq 2$ we have $\frac{(-1)^n}{n}\leq |\frac{(-1)^n}{n}|=\frac{1}{n}\leq\frac{1}{2}$. No need to use contradiction.

thanks for clarifying

Your proof for the first part is incorrect. When you assume that 1/2 is not an upper bound, it only implies that $\textit{there exists}$ an $n\in\mathbb{N}$ for which 1/2 < $\frac{(-1)^n}{n}$. You have assumed that this would hold $\textit{for all}$ $ n\in\mathbb{N}$, which is not a valid deduction to make. For example, using your argument you could also show that $0$ would be an upper bound for your set instead of 1/2.
A hint for showing that 1/2 is an upper bound: try to split the proof into two cases: one where n is odd and one where n is even. What can you say about $\frac{(-1)^n}{n}$ if n is odd, and what about if n is even?

So I initially did that and obviously when $n$ is odd, we'll always get a negative term. But if $n$ is even then the first term at n = 1 is 1/2 but then it will decrease with any larger n. It's how I saw that 1/2 must be the largest one. I'm not sure how to say this in a "formal proper way".

That is pretty much correct. You could just say that if n>2, it implies 1/n < 1/2. From there, the proof follows.

First notice that the absolute value of the $n^{\text{th}}$ term is is $\frac{1}{n}$. Next notice that the sequence of the absolute values of the terms is strictly decreasing. But then the supremum is the first positive term, that is to say $\frac{1}{2}$.
